# Detecting whether the CRT initialization was done in an injected process

Tags: c++, dll, code-injection, crt

I'm working on an application that injects a dll when a process starts (Suspend --> Inject --> Resume)
The very first call in DllMain with DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH (in the dll I injected) is a call to MessageBox() (just for debugging purpose).
However, this call to MessageBox() sometimes pops an error and crashes the injected process.

> Runtime Error!
> Program: C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE
> R6030
> - CRT not initialized

This is reproducible with Outlook and Winword for example. Though Notepad, IE, CMD, Calc and many others - print the message box and continue normally.

Printing a message box is not a must-have for me, so I just want to be able to check whether CRT has done initialization or not, so I can continue normally like this:

```
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
     if (IsCRTInitialized())
        MessageBox(...);
```

Please let me know if some information is missing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Kernel32.dll is guaranteed to be loaded in the process address space when the entry-point function **[DLLMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28VS.85%29.aspx)** is called. **MessageBox** resides in **user32.dll** and as per **[Best practices for creating DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx)** calling functions from **user32.dll** is a strict no-no.

You can either

1. Call **[OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** for any debugger tracing. This function resides in kernel32.dll and should be safe to call.
2. Before your application loads any other dlls, call **MessageBox** yourself. This will ensure that user32.dll and its dependencies are
   already loaded.  This way calling **MessageBox** in DllMain may have
   a better chance of succeeding.  But your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks @parapura. I'm aware of OutputDebugString (actually it is already in use). However this does not solve this issue. The main purpose for this message box is not just to show me some text, but to be able to debug-attach to any process creation in the very first steps of it. Most of the processes are able to call MessageBox() at this very early stage.

Comment: Continue:    I'm not trying to find a way to force the presence of a message box (I know I can't), but at least knowing that the CRT was not initialized will be good enough.  I thought I can try to check it using **GetModuleHanlde** on *user32.dll* (and not **LoadLibrary**) but I actually do get a valid handle HMODULE to *user32.dll*... I do not want to load *user32.dll* in my injected dll since it might not be needed.

Comment: If your goal is to debug attach process creation. Use [Image file executation options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks once again. The **Image file execution** is nice and useful, but this is still not what I'm looking for. Using it, any execution of a selected process will run in debug (even when my injected dll is not there) + another instance of VisualStudio is being launched instead of using the same one + I cannot use code-rules (for example, I want to be able to debug-attach only for exe(s) that have the substing "out" (outlook.exe / shout.exe ...) . Do you happen to know whether it is actually possible to know whether the CRT is already initialized?

Comment: @Elad I think you might have better luck somebody answering your question if you ask "How can I do blah" rather than how to find CRT is initialized. Launching exe from DllMain is not something people typically do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the CRT. You're not allowed to call `MessageBox` or any other non-trivial function from `DllMain`